# Joomla TinyMCE editor not supporting SVG Tag

Tags: php, svg, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I am trying to add `SVG` related data in a `Joomla` article which it doesn't support.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: improved formatting, added new tags

Comment: @OnurA. do you want to say that SVG is now supported in Joomla?

Comment: I've just edited your question, and added Joomla tag to improve your question's visibility since you have include Joomla keyword

Answer (score 0):

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    valid_elements : '*[*]'
})
```

Use valid_elements field in configuration to allow tags.